# Guava RateLimiter warmup clarification

Tags: java, guava

I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate how many QPS will happen at a certain time given that I am using Guava ratelimiter with warmpup. I read the comments [here](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SmoothRateLimiter.java), but it's still unclear to me. Hopefully someone here can clarify for me.

My use case:

I call an external service which has a 50 TPS limit. The caveat is, the first ~500 times we call them must be well below the 50 TPS afterwards we can resume 50TPS. (If there is a better solution than using the ratelimiter, I'd love to hear it!)

Psuedocode:

```
RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(50.0, 10, minutes);
for (String customerId : customerList) {
    rateLimiter.acquire();
    // call external service
}
```

Assuming we're only doing this with one thread. Is there a way to calculate what the TPS(QPS) will be at a given time? 3 minutes in? 5 minutes in? etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cold (minimum) rate of a `RateLimiter` with a `warmupPeriod` is 1/3 of the stable (maximum) rate (this is derived from the `coldFactor` hardcoded to `3.0` in [RateLimiter.java:147-184](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/6e5d50950189567224dcb57df026f08b0709a3ba/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.java#L147-L184)). Under saturated demand (i.e. uninterrupted requests for permits) the rate will increase at a constant rate until the stable (maximum) rate is reached.

As this is a [linear equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) we can write this in the form `y = m * x + b` where

- `y` (a.k.a `y(x)`), or `qps(t)`), is our expected QPS given a saturated period (e.g. 3 minutes in),
- `m` is the rate of change from our cold (minimum) rate to our stable (maximum) rate,
- `x` (or `t`) is the elapsed time under saturated demand, and
- `b` is our cold (minimum) rate (1/3 of our stable (maximum) rate).

Putting it altogether we have `qps(t) = (stableRate - coldRate) / warmupPeriod * saturatedPeriod + coldRate` where `coldRate = stableRate / 3`.

So for your example we can get the expected QPS at 3 minutes in:

```
qps(3) = (50.0 - 50.0/3.0) / 10.0 * 3.0 + 50.0/3.0 ~= 26.6666
```

Here is an implementation in Java:

```
/**
 * Calculates the expected QPS given a stableRate, a warmupPeriod, and a saturatedPeriod.
 * <p>
 * Both specified periods must use the same time unit.
 *
 * @param stableRate      how many permits become available per second once stable
 * @param warmupPeriod    the duration of the period where the {@code RateLimiter} ramps up
 *                        its rate, before reaching its stable (maximum) rate
 * @param saturatedPeriod the duration of the period for which the {@code RateLimiter} has
 *                        been under saturated demand starting from a cold state
 * @return The expected QPS assuming saturated demand starting from a cold state
 */
public static double qps(double stableRate, double warmupPeriod, double saturatedPeriod) {
    if (saturatedPeriod >= warmupPeriod) {
        return stableRate;
    }
    double coldRate = stableRate / 3.0;
    return (stableRate - coldRate) * saturatedPeriod / warmupPeriod + coldRate;
}
```

Note that in practice using a single thread you will not be able to saturate the demand on a `RateLimiter` so your actual QPS will be slightly lower than expected and will rarely (if ever) actually reach the stable (maximum) rate. Using multiple threads, however, will allow you to always have a pending permit request and saturate demand.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Clears things up.

Just to be certain, if I wanted to find the QPS at 3 minutes given the setup I mentioned in my post, would this be what the equation will look like?

Ratelimiter: RateLimiter.create(50.0, 10, minutes);

y = (10.0 [m] * 3.0 [x]) + (50/3.0) [b]

and y will be the QPS at 3 mins?

Comment: Not quite, it would actually be `(50.0 - 50.0/3.0) / 10.0 * 3.0 + 50.0/3.0`. I've updated my answer to try to clarify such. Thanks.

Comment: Very helpful answer, but I have to say this implementation seems really dumb to me.  Why not just expose the cold factor as externally configurable?  I want it to start at 0 and work its way up to the maximum, not start at 1/3 of the maximum...